# How can I increment the link

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have a link : https://www.glassdoor.ca/Job/canada-data-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,6_IN3_KE7,11_IP1.htm

I want to increment the link like this : https://www.glassdoor.ca/Job/canada-data-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,6_IN3_KE7,11_IP2.htm

then 3,4,5....
My code is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class GlassdoorSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = 'glassdoor'
#allowed_domains = ['https://www.glassdoor.ca/Job/canada-data-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,6_IN3_KE7,11.htm']
start_urls = ['https://www.glassdoor.ca/Job/canada-data-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,6_IN3_KE7,11_IP1.htm']

def parse(self, response):
    #main_url = "https://www.glassdoor.ca"
    urls = response.css('li.jl > div > div.flexbox > div > a::attr(href)').extract()

    for url in urls:            
            url = "https://www.glassdoor.ca" + url
            yield scrapy.Request(url = url, callback = self.parse_details)

    next_page_url = "https://www.glassdoor.ca/Job/canada-data-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,6_IN3_KE7,11_IP" 
    if next_page_url:
       #next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url) 
       yield scrapy.Request(url = next_page_url, callback = self.parse)  

def parse_details(self,response):
    yield{
        'Job_Title' : response.css('div.header.cell.info > h2::text').extract()

    }
    self.log("reached22: "+ response.url)
```

I want to increment it in the variable next_page_url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that it's not found in the page source on the same place as when you inspect the page. However, you can see it's present in the page source under `<head>` as

```
<link rel="next" href="https://www.monster.ca/jobs/search/?q=data-analyst&amp;page=2" />
```

You can extract it using

```
next_page_link = response.xpath('//head/link[@rel="next"]/@href').extract_first()
```

Comment: Cool way, but I know it is not possible but for every page you Xpath query is giving me the same result that is : https://www.monster.ca/jobs/search/?q=data-analyst&amp;page=2 .


even for : https://www.monster.ca/jobs/search/?q=data-analyst&page=6  xpath is giving link for page number 2. Could you please check.

Comment: @AshishKapil Are you sure? It works for me, for the 6th page it gives me `Out[1]: u'https://www.monster.ca/jobs/search/?q=data-analyst&page=7'` in Scrapy shell.

Comment: Your query is perfect, I guess I have an issue at my end, whatever page I am giving to scrapy shell no matter what it is loading the first page only.

Thanks a lot again Tomas :))

Comment: @AshishKapil You can update the question with record of Scrapy shell session so we can take a look, maybe we find out what's the issue.

Comment: Hi,I have added the shell's screenshot in which I am giving the link of page 3 , but it is still giving me page=2 , (that means it is still hitting the first page)

Comment: @AshishKapil I think I know where's the problem. Try to put the URL you give to Scrapy shell on command line into quotes. The `page` parameter gets lost without them, look at URL in the log output: `DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET ...>`.

Comment: Tomas,It worked successfully thanks a lot, I owe you big time. Thanks for your genuine help :))

Answer (score 2):

for getting the **second page** you can you this

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Referer': 'https://www.monster.ca/jobs/search/?q=data-analyst',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
}
#for the other page, you should change page number
params = (
    ('q', 'data-analyst'),
    ('page', '2'),
)

r = requests.get('https://www.monster.ca/jobs/search/', headers=headers, params=params)
print r.text
```

for getting all pages, you should get the number of last page,

```
for page_number in xrange(2, last_page):
   #put page_number in params
```

**UPDATE 1**

ANOTHER SOLUTION

[image]

```
def start_requests(self):
    request =  Request("https://www.monster.ca/jobs/search/?q=data-analyst", callback=self.get_lastPage)
    yield request

def get_lastPage(self,response):
    headers = {
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Referer': 'https://www.monster.ca/jobs/search/?q=data-analyst',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    }
    last_page = response.css('input#totalPages::attr("value")').extract_first()
    for last_page in xrange(2, int(last_page)):
        link = "https://www.monster.ca/jobs/search/?q=data-analyst&page=" + str(last_page)
        yield Request(link,
                        headers=headers, 
                        callback=self.parse_product)
```

Comment: If I leave aside that your approach involves using `requests` instead of Scrapy, then there are two other points. First you can pass the query parameters right away in the URL, and second you don't give a hint about how to get the last page number.

Comment: @TomášLinhart  He asked how to call 'next page' and my answer shows him to how to go to the next page, you're right, we can pass the parameter, but my answer is not wrong and there is no reason for your negative point :) anyway i think it's too clear for getting last page and we're not here to do ALL parts of code, but i edit my answer and tell him how to do that!

Comment: IMHO the answer should be complete without any intentionally missing information (e.g. where to get the last page number). Also, when you use approach involving other tools than what OP uses (`requests` library instead of native Scrapy solution), you should give a hint about how to solve the issue in his current settings (i.e. how to extract information from response from `requests.get()` call).

Comment: @TomášLinhart you just justifie your negative point despite of my correct answer, ok np, i edited my post and  give him a complete  answer with Request !

Answer (score 0):

You need XPath expression in this manner

```
urls = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"next")]//@href')
```

Try,it should work.

Comment: No, it returns nothing. :/

I think they are using javascript for the pagination, that is why we are not able to hit the link through HTML parsing